# Format a date using a specific format

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I have `31 juli 2021` (norwegian date formatting), and adding 14 days to it, which gives me `14.08.2021`.

I would like for the return date to be in the same format: `14 august 2021`.

This is my current code:

```
int yearInt = Convert.ToInt32(year);
int monthInt = Convert.ToInt32(month);
int lastDayOfMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(yearInt, monthInt);
DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
DateTime invoiceDate = new(yearInt, monthInt, lastDayOfMonth);
DateTime invoiceDatePlus14 = invoiceDate.AddDays(14);
string rsvpBy_monthIsInt = invoiceDayPlus14.ToShortDateString();
```

I know how to get the month name off of the its corresponding `int` value:

```
static string getMonthName(int month) {

    return CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("no").DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(month);
}
```

But how can I do the same to `monthInt` without re-factoring my whole approach?
If I need to - I need to, if so, how could I?

Comment: Are you actually asking how to get the number month from a `DateTime`?

Comment: Note that format only applies to when you convert your `DateTime` to a `string` and you can specify any format you want like `"dd MMMM yyyy"` which should be the format you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to try this:

```
string rsvpBy_monthIsInt = invoiceDayPlus14.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy");
```

Comment: Or `string rsvpBy_monthIsInt = $"{invoiceDayPlus:dd MMMM yyyy}"`

Comment: Thanks @DmitryBychenko, is there a performance difference, you think?

Comment: @Ole M: I expect miniscule difference, if any: *string interpolation* will be changed into *formatting* by compiler